# Using Memory Disk for I/O unit tests

Tags: c#, nunit, moq, ramdisk

I have a following setup in C# - I have a component which gets a folder path in the constructor, and later, some huge data are processed by it and written out to disk in form of several files (order of magnitude about 1Gb, very IO intensive). On retrieve, the data are read in (also IO intense), and my unit test (nunit with MOQ, setup as in fact a component test) compares them with the original data. The problem - the unit test takes several minutes to complete, what is quite annoying. I thought, is there a way to create a RAMDrive or RAMFolder in the test fixture setup, and remove it in tear down. I cant use the memory files or memory streams, as outside of the component noone should know which files are used exactly.

Any idea?

Best regards,
Petr

Answer (score 1):

1. Get an SSD
2. Cut down unit test
3. Abstract storage access away in a sub-component separately tested... and then mock that using array in memory to simulate files.

Three doable ways of doing this. I would try going with 3 - and STILL buy a SSD. SSD are great for tons of small IO stuff, and guess what a compile is (even C# - tons of source files).

Comment: SSD would be nice, but it would need to be not one, but 1 per employee (TDD, run all tests before deliver policy) and also for several build servers - thats not (yet ;)) my decision level. Cutting down unit test is also out of question here. Adding a sub-component level - maybe, I would need to consider this, but it would need introduction on much more then one component, too.

Comment: Well, I replace all discs with 120gb ssd for devs now. Plus - my build server gates the checkin (builds and tests on the server before merging the changes into trunk).

Comment: Well, if you could convince the company to switch all 5000 developers to SSDs, or at least our dep't of about 250 people - I would of course be game ;)

Comment: It is quite easy - seriously. I dont know how much YOU pay developers, but in my world (and level) the cost of a 120gb SSD is equal to about an hour invoices time. Evn in india or chiang the infrastructure cost for 5000 develoeprs totally dwarfs the cost for the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to tear it down after the test? Why not just empty all files after your unit tests in a `ClassCleanup`?

As RAMdisk software, you may want to check out RAMDisk 11 at http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/ramdisk.php.

You could of course also mock out the actual writing of the files, could you not?

Comment: I have investigated the RAMDisk shortly, but it needs installation. For me, it would be much better to get a solution not requiring installation as it would need to be installed on several build servers (not really accessible for me) and on all employee machines. Probably need to search for mocking options here...

Answer (score 0):

i would try to have the businessobject with two apis one with filenames (for existing code) and one with streams.

the file api is just a thin layer  that converts calls to the streamapi where the processing  is done.

the unittests can use the stream-api (ie a memorystream) while the wole system works with filestreams via the fileapi